# Appropriate site for question regarding my findings?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I did some research about solving a problem and have couple of possible solutions. One of them seems most appropriate according to my requirements. I would like to share my findings and confirm if my final chosen selection make sense and I am not missing anything major.

Is this type of question appropriate for Super User? If not is there any forum for this type of question?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? In theory, yes, you can post your own question and answer if you've solved your problem: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) – other than that you could also simply ask a question, list the solutions, and then ask which would be the most appropriate one. But without a specific example it's hard to tell whether that would be a *good*, on topic question.

Comment: "you could also simply ask a question, list the solutions, and then ask which would be the most appropriate one" That answers my question. Thanks

Comment: Well… No guarantees without seeing an example of what you want to ask though. But sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

[Been there, done that](https://superuser.com/questions/523928/how-do-i-run-the-integrated-video-adaptor-alongside-the-gpu-on-a-ivy-ridge-syste).

Its [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) - just remember to phrase your question as a *question*, and select the self answer tickbox and post a properly worded answer - a lot of people lapse into posting a forum style post.

Just remember that if the question seems non constructive or attempting to solicit a list, it might get closed/

Comment: Given the info we have, I'm not even sure the OP has a definitive solution to post as an answer.

Comment: "Just remember that if the question seems non constructive or attempting to solicit a list, it might get closed" - Yup, if it's just an attempt to elicit opinion and is likely to generate debate, it's not appropriate.